# Show that if $A\subset B$ then $A^a \subset B^a$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As stated in the title the problem reads, show that if $A\subset B$ then $A^a\subset B^a$. I'm dealing with topologies here and they are relatively new to me so I'm trying to understand them better. In this case "a" refers to the accumulation/limit point.

So the definition I have for accumulation point is as follows:

$x\in A^a\iff\forall(G\in\tau,x\in G) G\cap A\nsubseteq \{x\}$

$G\cap A\nsubseteq \{x\}$ is the same as $\exists y\neq x\in G\cap A$.

I'm having trouble starting because I know my hypothesis is that $A\subset B$ however from there should I assume $x\in A^a$ and thus end up ultimately proving that $x\in B^a$?

Comment: What is $A^a$ ?

Comment: @Sou the accumulation points of $A$?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question for better understanding, the little "a" refers to the accumulation/limit point.

Comment: @LuisRobles $A^a \subset B^a$ still true even if $A^a = \emptyset$.

Comment: If you want to convey the notion of $X\subseteq Y\land Y\ne X$, you can use the $\subsetneq$ (subsetneq) or $\subsetneqq$ (subsetneqq) symbols (and likewise "supsetneq" or "supsetneqq"). In my opinion, the work better than any "nsubseteq" machinery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in A^a$ and let $G$ be an open set such that $x\in G$. Let $y\in A\cap G$, $y\ne x$. Then $y\in B$, so $y\in B\cap G$.

Thus every open set containing $x$ intersects $B$ at a point different from $x$, which is the condition for $x\in B^a$.

---

Alternatively, suppose $x\notin B^a$; then there exists an open set $G$ such that $x\in G$ and $B\cap G\subseteq\{x\}$. Then $A\cap G\subseteq B\cap G\subseteq\{x\}$, so $x\notin A^a$.

Comment: Thank you, so the very last part would be a contradiction since our assumption stated that $x\in A^a$ right?

Comment: @LuisRobles There's no need to use contradiction for the alternative proof: you show that the complement of $B^a$ is contained in the complement of $A^a$, which obviously implies the inclusion you want to show.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you!